# Node with Express: Storing session variables, multiple response.status updates

Tags: node.js, express, response

I have an app which runs lengthy processes in node. I limit these lengthy processes to one per user.

When a user starts a lengthy process I do

```
req.session.busy = true;
req.session.save();
```

When the process is finished I do

```
req.session.busy = false;
res.status(200).json({
  done: true
});
```

If a user tries to start another lengthy process in the meantime I do

```
if (req.session.busy) {
    res.status(200).json({
        busy: true
    });
}
```

What I would like to do is to send a response to confirm that request has been received.

```
res.status(200).json({
  process_started: true
});
```

But this ends the response. I can no longer set busy = false at the end of the running process and send a response that the process is finished.

Is there any way I can save the session, send a status that the request has been received and then send the status(200) response when the process is finished?

Perhaps there is another status than 200 which will keep the response alive in node.

I tried

```
res.status(100).json({
  process_started: true
});
```

Hoping that the http status code 100 - Informal (continue) would do the trick, but no cigar. The application will crash when I try to send the status(200) thereafter. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: Probably want to look into web sockets (socket.io for node)

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that you can only send a response **once**. When the page is loaded, it will not "wait" for another response and update itself, it's done. That's the reason you cannot send another response.

1. First option: Display a site which polls the results (or even the progress) via AJAX. You'd have to serve the state to a third route somewhere and then poll this third route.
2. Second option: Use sockets to send the data to the user (see: http://socket.io/)